# Multiple filter data dropdown table with plotly in python

Tags: python, plotly, interactive, plotly-python

I am currently trying to generate a table with multiple dropdown options (in a Jupiter Notebook). I have been able to create the scenario but the dropdown buttons work independently, meaning that if I select one dropdown from my 'Decision' dropdown with option 'A' and then select the other downtown 'Sex' with option 'Female' I either get option A or option 2 depending on the button last selected. However, what I really want is to have both filters applied at the same time. So I would get all Decisions 'A' that are 'Female' as filters for my table.

This is my code:

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Table(header={"values": df_dash.columns,'fill_color':'navy','align':'left',
                                 'font':dict(color='white', size=12)}, 
                         cells={"values": df_dash.T.values,'fill_color':'white','align':'left'}))
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "y": 1 - (i / 5),
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": c,
                    "method": "restyle",
                    "args": [
                        {
                            "cells": {
                                "values": df_dash.T.values
                                if c == "All"
                                else df_dash.loc[df_dash[menu].eq(c)].T.values
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                }
                for c in ["All"] + df_dash[menu].unique().tolist()
                
            ],
            
        }
        for i, menu in enumerate(["Decision", "Sex",])
    ]
)
```

And this is how it looks:

[image: Table view]

Any ideas what am I doing wrong or what can I add to make both buttons actively filtering my df table at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://community.plotly.com/t/plotly-buttons-with-dependent-interactions/18653/2) in the plotly forums, you cannot create buttons that are dependent on each other.

The best you could probably do is create one dropdown with every possible combination in your current `Decision` and `Sex` dropdowns – which I understand probably isn't ideal.

If you are willing to use `plotly-dash`, then it is possible as you can create two dropdowns that are inputs to a basic callback that updates the fig, as shown in [this example](https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks#dash-app-with-multiple-inputs) in the plotly-dash documentation

Comment: Thank you, that is of great help, unfortunately for the project I cannot use plotly-dash but will try your other idea