# Plotly: Select data with multiple dropdown menus from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, drop-down-menu, plotly

I want to create an interactive figure with plotly graph objects, where I can select the data from two dropdown menus. The menus should  select the specific data from a dataframe.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
    mode    y   x1  x2
0   A   3   0   6
1   A   4   1   7
2   A   2   2   8
3   B   1   3   9
4   B   0   4   10
5   B   5   5   11
```

I want the first dropdownmenu to choose between mode "A" and "B", and the second to choose between "x1" and "x2".

The first menu works perfectly:

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df["x1"], y=df[df["mode"]=="A"]["y"]))
            
buttons = []
for modes in list(df["mode"].unique()):
    buttons.append(
        dict(
            args=[{"y":[df[df["mode"]==modes]["y"]],
                   "x":[df[df["mode"]==modes]["x1"]]
            }],
            label = modes,
            method = "restyle"
        )
    )

fig.update_layout(
      updatemenus=[go.layout.Updatemenu(buttons=buttons)],
      # second menu
)
```

For the second menu, I tried adding:

```
buttons=list([
                dict(
                    args= [{"x":[df["x1"]] }],
                    label= "x1",
                    method="restyle"),
                dict(
                    args= [{"x":[df["x2"]] }],
                    label= "x2",
                    method="restyle")
             ])
```

which adds a drowpdown menu, but not with the right functionality. It doesn't choose the "correct" x2 values, if you select "B" in the first menu.

And here lies the problem:
I think I need to add something in the direction of:

```
dict(
                    args= [{"x":[df[df["mode"] == **current mode from menu 1** ]["x1"]] }],
                    label= "x1",
                    method="restyle"
)
```

in order to choose the correct x2 values, but I don't know how.

That's as far as I got, but I'm not finding any way to do it. I've already tried searching for but didn't come up with a solution.

My desired output:

```
A and x1: plots y(A,x1) -> (0,3)(1,4)(2,2) 
A and x2: plots y(A,x2) -> (6,3)(7,4)(8,2) 
B and x1: plots y(B,x1) -> (3,1)(4,0)(5,5)
B and x2: plots y(B,x2) -> (9,1)(10,0)(11,5)
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = {'mode': ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],'y': [3, 4, 2, 1, 0, 5], 'x1': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'x2': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df["x1"], y=df[df["mode"]=="A"]["y"]))
            
buttons = []
for modes in list(df["mode"].unique()):
    buttons.append(
        dict(
            args=[{"y":[df[df["mode"]==modes]["y"]],
                   "x":[df[df["mode"]==modes]["x1"]]
                 }],
            label = modes,
            method = "restyle")
     )
    
    


fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        go.layout.Updatemenu(buttons=buttons),
        dict(
            buttons=list([
                dict(
                    args= [{"x":[df["x1"]] }],
                    label= "x1",
                    method="restyle"),
                dict(
                    args= [{"x":[df["x2"]] }],
                    label= "x2",
                    method="restyle")
            ]),
        y=0.2
        )
     ]
)

fig
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `df['y']` to the `arg` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

data = {'mode': ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],'y': [3, 4, 2, 1, 0, 5], 'x1': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'x2': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df["x1"], y=df[df["mode"]=="A"]["y"]))
            
buttons = []
for modes in list(df["mode"].unique()):
    buttons.append(
        dict(
            args=[{"y":[df[df["mode"]==modes]["y"].tolist()],
                   "x":[df[df["mode"]==modes]["x1"].tolist()]
                 }],
            label = modes,
            method = "restyle")
     )
    
    


fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        
        go.layout.Updatemenu(buttons=buttons),
        go.layout.Updatemenu(
            buttons=list([
                dict(
                    args= [{"x":[df["x1"]], "y":[df["y"]]}], #<----------
                    label= "x1",
                    method="update"),
                dict(
                    args= [{"x":[df["x2"]], "y":[df["y"]]}],  #<----------
                    label= "x2",
                    method="update")
            ]),
        y=0.2,
        )
     ]
)

fig
```

**Output**
[image]

Comment: I editet my question to show my desired output. If you select "x2" in your solution it plots 6 points. I only want it to plot the 3 points definded by A/B and x1/x2.

Comment: @imeatingchili both menus should work together as filters.

Comment: Yes that would be great. But your solution doesnt apply the correct "filter" for the x1/x2. I think whats missing is, as i mentiond in the question, that the second menu has a condition for the "modes", wether to plot y(x2 **A**) or y(x2 **B**)

Comment: @imeatingchili https://stackoverflow.com/a/72724107/16733101